# Xamarin forces me to download Android SDK and NDK

Tags: android, xamarin

I have my Android SDK and NDK installed on my computer (On custom locations) . I am trying to install xamarin on my Windows environment but the installer wants to force me to install SDK and NDK . It looks like it cannot find by installations folder. Is there a solution to specify when my SDK and NDK are installed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I finally managed to get The installer detect my sdk location. Here's what I did:

- Install Xamarin Studio Alone (https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads)
- Change your SDK , NDK , JDK Locations in Xamarin Studio settings and close
- Download the Universal Installer and start
- It will automatically detect that Xamarin Studio installed and will use its settings.
- Install other dependencies
- Start visual studio and enjoy !

The Xamarin Team really need to add the possibilty to select your SDK/NDK/JDK locations at INSTALLATION TIME

Comment: surprisingly this is still and issue on Mac and installing Xamarin Studion alone isn't an option

Answer (score 2):

According to the Xamarin docs you can configure where it looks for the SDKs:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Xamarin_Studio

Comment: I have not installed Xamari yet . I downloaded the Installer but It doesn't detect my SDK/NDK installations .  And there's no option to select where is my SDK or NDK