# Xamarin Installer doesn't recognize installed Android SDK on my Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sdk-2.3

Apparently this is not a problem and someone proposed a solution that apparently works [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147143/xamarin-forces-me-to-download-android-sdk-and-ndk), this issue still exists on Mac. 
Although the SDK installed by Android Studio on its default path (`/Users/user/Library/Android`) exists, Xamarin installer still wants to download a "private copy of android sdk":

[image]

Does anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. You can either add the path to the downloaded SDK by clicking the + button, or create folders in the default Xamarin location and then copy the sdk there.

Even though I tried this, a new Android SDK had just been released. The Xamarin installer was intent on downloading the latest version though, and I eventually ended up leaving it to complete.

Comment: yeah I've tried the copy/pasting of a 20 gb folder and it didn't work. I think I need to start downloading too.

Comment: Spent hours trying to get around this, also had a large folder with plenty of SDKs. Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the Android SDK Location in Xamarin Studio to use what was already installed on my mac:

- Xamarin Studio top right menu
- Xamarin Studio Community
- Preferences
- SDK Locations
- Android
- Android SDK Location : Browse and choose the location of your android install; it's usually at the following location on a mac ->   user/Library/Android/sdk